# Minimum length for ido-completing-read

Tags: projectile, ido, flx-ido

I'm trying to write an `ido-completing-read`-powered backend for `projectile-find-tag`.

However, for really big TAG files, this is ridiculously slow when the user starts typing because there are so many completion options.

How can I stop ido from trying to offer suggestions until the user has entered X many characters?

(I'm using `flx-ido` if that matters)